# Making JScrollPane snap to the top

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

So, I have a program that opens a document and displays it. However, document is often to big for the display area so I added a JScrollPane. Due to the way I'm adding the elements to the display, I always end up at the end of the document after loading it. i cannot change the way I load the document, but I'd like to change the way JScrollPane acts after the load.

How can I force it to snap to the top? I tried with scrollRectToVisible for a top component, but that didn't work.

Is there a method I could use to make it set it's position to top (it's a vertical JScrollpane only)?

edit: I messed up, it's JScrollPane, not JScrollBar.

edit2:

I decided to go with this:

```
myScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
```

In JFileChooser construcor:

```
...
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
...
Main.myScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
}
```

That doesn't work. If I move it to my JMenu object and add a flag it looks like this:

In JFileChooser construcor:

```
...
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
{
...
Main.flag = true;
}
```

In JMenu constructor:

```
...
someJMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
new MyJFileChooser();
if (Main.flag)
{
Main.myScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0);
Main.flag = false;
}
}
}
```

This also doesn't work, but I know that the code inside the if command is executing.

If I attach Main.myScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0); to a butten in JMenu, it will work flawlessly.

So, what's wrong?

Comment: myPanel.scrollRectToVisible(myPanel.getBounds()) should work - if it doesn't something is wrong somewhere else ..

Comment: Could it be issue with EDT? I'm invoking it inside a JFileChooser constructor inside a JMenuItem. JMenu is in main JFrame.

Answer (score 2):

1. depends of `program that opens a document and displays it` have to keep the `Caret` possition to the zero
2. have to move with `JScrollBar` to the zero value
3. move with `JViewport` to (0, 0)  (`scrollRectToVisible for a top component`)
4. for better help sooner post an SSCCE, because this answer here is only about theory

edit

as `@Joop Eggen` correctly noticed, in most cases required (view_to_model) wrapped in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`

Comment: Let's say it's I have a JPanel in JScrollPane filled with other components, but there is a space inbetween the top of the JPanel and the first component. I want to make JScrollPane to snap to the top of JPanel (put it in topmost position). Just that.

Comment: nothing complicated move with `JViewport` to the desired (`scrollToVisibleRectangle(whatever.getBounds()`) from `JPanel` or nested `JComponents`, that have got a) already visible, b) packed, c) returns getBounds(), everything is implemented in Java4, sorry for possible typos, only built_in compilator, sent from cell phone

Comment: don't forget to set scrollIncrement for JPanel inside JScrollPane, because scrollable JComponents returns 3 rows, JPanel 10pixels, scrolling isn't natural :-)

Comment: Okay, I figured this out. myScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(0); This works when I call it in the main class, but won't work when I call it from JFolderChooser constructor. How can I pass the information to call it when it closes?

Comment: all three ways are correct, but each of them is suitable for diferrent part of `JComponents`, `scrollToVisibleRectangle(whatever.getBounds()` works for all three parts of ....

Comment: again I linked you very clear code in your last post about de_javu, JFileChooser returns JTable or JList, use JFileCHooser properly, there must be methods to retunrs last file or first file, should be more that crazy if not (based on proeprties that came from Native OS) :-)

Comment: Let's not forget `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.